# How to keep the alignment of equation array on a new page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I have a very long equations inside

```
\begin{eqnarray}
   long equation go over 2 pages...
\end{eqnarray}
```

I can't break into two by

```
 \begin{eqnarray}
          1/n of long
    \end{eqnarray}
    \begin{eqnarray}
          b/n of long
    \end{eqnarray}
```

Unfortunately, the alignment is gone since the alignment of the second page is based on the first equation on the second page. I wonder is there a way to keep the same alignment for a really long equations?

Comment: best to avoid `eqnarray` altogether and use `align` and friends from `amsmath`; see [eqnarray-vs-align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of using `eqnarray`, use `align` (or any of the other environments provided by the `amsmath` package). During the document preparation, using `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]` in the preamble, allows an individual automatic page break inside displayed equations; a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{amsmath}

\allowdisplaybreaks[1]

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &= b \\
&= c \\
&= c \\
&= c \\
&= c \\
&= c \\
&= c \\
&= c 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **egreg** mentions in his comment, once the document is finished, is best to suppress `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]` from the preamble and use `\displaybreak` inside the corresponding displayed equation and put it in the best place for the break (which may not be the one automatically chosen); this command is best placed immediately before the line change command where it is to take effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &= b \\
&= c \\
&= c \\
&= c \displaybreak\\
&= c \\
&= c \\
&= c \\
&= c 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The reasons for not using `eqnarray` can be found in [`Avoid eqnarray!`](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) by Lars Madsen.

Comment: This is right when working on the document. In the final revision `\allowdisplaybreaks` should be disabled and `\displaybreak` put in the best place for a break, which may not be the one chosen automatically.

Comment: @egreg I added your comment to my answer. Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice if latex had a way to write displaybreak[30], which would change the breaking penalty.  Then, you could put optional displaybreaks everywhere, and latex would choose the best one(s).

Comment: Let me tell you that this site is awesome. Many of the things that I don't know how to do in LaTeX were already asked and answered by someone here in this site! :)

Comment: Why `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]` should be avoided in the final document version? Why is it no good to leave it like that?

Comment: @Vincent because the automatic break point produced by `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]` might not necessarily be the best one.